# Docker with postgresql in flask web application

Tags: python, postgresql, docker, flask, sqlalchemy

I am building a Flask application in Python. I'm using SQLAlchemy to connect to PostgreSQL.

In the flask application, I'm using this to connect SQLAlchemy to PostgreSQL

```
engine = create_engine('postgresql://postgres:[mypassword]@db:5432/employee-manager-db')
```

And this is my docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  backend:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/app

    depends_on:
      - db

  db:
    image: postgres:14.5
    restart: always
    expose:
      - '5432'
    volumes:
      - .dbdata:/var/lib/postgresql
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: [mypassword]
```

However, I get an error saying "Is the server running on host "db" (172.21.0.2) and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?"

These are my docker containers:

[image]

Inside the employee-manager_db_1, it says "PostgreSQL init process complete; ready for start up". Inside the employee-manager_backend_1, it says "psycopg2.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection refused. Is the server running on host "db" (172.21.0.2) and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?"

Thank you so much for help.

Comment: Hi, 
Check for logs if the DB has started successfully, if yes, try to check if you can resolve db hostname from backend container to db. You probably don't need those expose and ports statements, as postgres image has already specified what it needs to expose.

Comment: Can you [edit] the question to replace the image file with the text of the error message?  That will be much easier to read and search for later.  (As a general rule you should almost never include screen shots of terminal windows in SO questions.)

Comment: Thank you so much for your comments! I edited the post and added more details. Sorry @GRzA I'm not sure what to do when you said "check if you can resolve db hostname from backend container to db". Sorry I only studied software engineering for a month and idk what's going on at all

Comment: It's possible you have a race condition -- your backend may be attempting to contact the database before the database is ready to handle connections. You should write your application to handle this situation: put a loop around that `create_engine(...)` statement and loop (possibly printing diagnostics of some sort) until it is successful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it adding pgadmin service.

```
  pgadmin:
    image: 'dpage/pgadmin4'
    restart: always
    ....
```